# subquery Sequelize with nested query (include)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this two models :

```
const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      default: true
    },
    image: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Category.associate = function (models) {
    Category.hasMany(models.Product)
    Category.hasMany(models.Category, { as: 'child', foreignKey: 'ParentId' });
    Category.belongsTo(models.Category, { as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'ParentId' });
  };
  return Category;

const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
    description: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      default: true
    },
    image: DataTypes.STRING,

  }, {});
  Product.associate = function (models) {
    Product.belongsTo(models.Category)
  };
  return Product;
```

nothing fancy here .my category model can has a CategoryId for nested purposes.so my question is is there a way I can have a subquery in Category model that select products with a related category Id?

```
Category.findAll({
        limit: page_size,
        where: {
            ParentId: {
                [sequelize.Op.eq]: null
            }
        },
        include: [{

            model: Category,
            as: "child",
            attributes: [
                [sequelize.literal('(SELECT * FROM "Products" WHERE "CategoryId" = "child"."id")'),
                    'products'],
            ],
            group: ['products']
        }],
        offset: offset_value,
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC'],
        ],
    })
```

I tried to include and in the include section I need to query to my products that group it as a field.

> p.s: if category instance has no CategoryId it will be considered as
>   Parent.

and I wrote this query and tested it comes with this error:

> subquery must return only one column

Comment: use [sequelize-hirearchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy) as fast solution.

Comment: hey did u get answer to the above question